# Makefile target with clashing patterns

Tags: makefile

I have this peculiar situation. I will explain what I need to do

I have a bunch of .c files and I need to get .s files out of them.

My order of compilation is as follows

`filename.c -> filename.ll -> filename_reg.ll -> filename_reg.s`

Now the obvious issue is that both the second and third stage have clashing patterns, i.e. the pattern for filename.ll also matches filename_reg.ll

So I did the simple thing of writing the %_reg.ll pattern before the %.ll pattern. So that it will be matched first.

But then it can't find the %.ll pattern which is defined after it.

Any work around for this?

Comment: Assuming that the `filename_reg.s` is an assembler file, what are the intermediate files? What is their purpose? Can't you generate the assembler file directly from the C source file (most compilers can do that)?

Comment: I am working on a non standard compiler (a fork of LLVM/CLANG) and it has to be done in stages.

Comment: So the intermediate `.ll` files serve some other purpose? Because unless you removed the `-S` option from your fork of Clang I don't see a purpose for them. Can you just reassure me that the `.ll` files are needed for *something else* than just steps to create the assembler file? If not, then the solution is to use the `-S` option and don't care about the intermediate files.

Comment: Okay, I will tell you why I have to do them multistaged. I have added some passes my of my own to run with opt. I have made a *lot* of changes in llc (.ll -> .s) and have to keep on doing changes. The front end clang is also modified to some extent. Now in the process of bug fixing I need to run just the llc step again(after making changes in llc). If I do it all the way from clang again, I will have to rerun the front end. Also compiling clang itself takes insane amount of time. So right now this is the only path feasible for me. Thanks

Comment: Also the purpose of make would be to avoid the overheads of parsing the c run the opt passes etc.

Comment: You would have to show your makefile.  What you're describing should work.   As a general rule, make will find the pattern rule with the shortest stem, and run that for a particular target, so it shouldn't matter what order the rules are in -- if the file ends with `_reg.ll`, it will run the `%_reg.ll` rule, and if it ends with `.ll`, but doesn't match `%_reg.ll`, it would run the other one.

Comment: @John. Thanks. This works. Although I fixed it by placing the ll and reg files in different folders. This solution is cleaner though. My Makefile wasn't working because I placed the .ll target after thr _reg.ll target. I was confused into thinking that order is what decides the matching. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment -- what you describe should work.  Make will always match the rule with the shortest stem, so it won't matter the order the two pattern rules for the `.ll` files are in.   If I have:

```
%_reg.s: %_reg.ll
    @echo "$^ -> $@" && cp $^ $@

%_reg.ll: %.ll
    @echo "$^ -> $@" && cp $^ $@

%.ll: %.c
    @echo "$^ -> $@" && cp $^ $@
```

And I run `make filename.s`, I get:

```
~/sandbox/tst6>  make filename_reg.s
filename.c -> filename.ll
filename.ll -> filename_reg.ll
filename_reg.ll -> filename_reg.s
rm filename.ll filename_reg.ll
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Although I solved it by placing the reg and ll files in different folders. But this solution is cleaner.

Comment: Note that the "shortest stem matches" algorithm was implemented in GNU make 3.82.  Prior to that make would use the first matching pattern regardless of stem length.  If you want to be portable, order your patterns so that the shortest stem is also the first pattern and it will work with both older and newer versions of GNU make.

Comment: @MadScientist but in the first matching case it can't find the rule for the `.ll` because it is after the rule for `_reg.ll`.

Comment: When you try to build `filename_reg.ll` it will match the `%_reg.ll : %.ll` pattern because (in older version of make) it comes first in the makefile or (in newer versions of make) it has the shortest stem.  When you try to build `filename.ll` it can't use the pattern `%_reg.ll : %.ll` because the target you're trying to build, `filename.ll` doesn't match the pattern `%_reg.ll`.  So it will ignore that pattern and use the first _matching_ pattern, which will be `%.ll: %.c`.